# Multivariate Goodness of fit test for Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, estimation, goodness-of-fit

So I am doing research at the moment, and I wish to test out the accuracy of my estimation methods. I'd like to apply a goodness of fit test for my distributions.
I was hoping that Matlab would have a native way to do this, or maybe someone already wrote some sort of code for this.

Now my work is as follows:
I have a Multivariate Modified Pareto distribution with *n* observations.
After simulating it, I will have a *n* by *m*, matrix, where *m* is the number of Depended-Pareto Random variable.

I'd like to run something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html), only generalized to *m*-dimensions, or preferably a *Kolmogorov-Test*.

In so far, with my research I only found a way to do this with Copulas, but its not exactly what I want.

I could write my own code, but I was hoping there is something that has already been written and tested by the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after waiting a while, I ended up writing my own function.
If anyone is in need of this, or is interested in contributing, here is my repo
https://github.com/asosnovsky/Matlab.Multivariate.Chi.Test